# jenkins maven metadata plugin, build with parameters not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, artifactory

I don´t know if I´m using it right, but I have an artifactory repo working ok , and I can upload or download artifact from jenkins manualy using CURL. Now I want to use this plugin to choose the war that I want as parameter to download in the pipeline script, but I´m getting following error.

What Am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: macen-metadata.xml exists in your artifactory in the expected path ?

Comment: yes I read that, and this the first time Im working with this. The final PATH of the URL leads to the artifact itself. What is That XML refer to in Artifactory? When I created the repository and added the WARs files I didn´t see anthing related to a XML. Do you know how this works Between artifactory and jenkins?

Comment: You need to build & publish to Artifactory using maven first. Then a maven-metadata.xml file is created and you should be able to use the plugin to list maven artifacts.

Comment: ok, can this be achieve using a maven proyect in jenkins? or needs to be done manually from jenkins server (which of course has maven installed)? Have never create a maven repor/proyect before. thanks

Comment: Yes, for ex. in our setup, we use a pipeline to build and publish the artifact to Artifactory using Artifactory Maven plugin. I will post a snippet of code we use to build & publish in the answer below for easy readability and as it's too long for a comment. We have another pipeline that lists all the artifacts which user can choose to deploy.

Comment: hmm didn´t know all this. I also Have a pipeline in groovy that creates the WAR with few steps and upload it in artifactory. First step code chekout, second step sh "mvn clean compile war:war" and finally : sh 'curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD -T target/gp_-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war "https://artifactory.xxxx.com:443/artifactory/search-api/gp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"'.

Comment: clearly this way is incompatible with what you are suggesting. Will have to check how to achieve this with the example yo said. Is that groovy as well? or just a maven proyect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182046/discussion-between-ben5556-and-yiyito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - Continuation from comment above:

```
// Create an Artifactory instance
def server = Artifactory.server('Artifactory-1')

// Create an Artifactory Maven Build instance
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

// Set path to Maven installation directory
env.MAVEN_HOME = '/opt/apache-maven-3.5.3/'

rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: '<repo-name-in-artifactory>'

// Define maven goal
def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -D releaseVersion="${BUILD_NUMBER}"'

// Build
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo

// Publish build info
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```